# C# Extension Methods not working in .NET Core App

Tags: c#, extension-methods

This is my first foray into .NET Core.  **The following code works, and has worked for years** in regular ASP.NET applications.  But in my first .NET Core app, the extension methods are reporting undefined.

```
namespace CoreAPI1 {

    class SQL_Data {

        public SqlDataReader DBReader(string query) {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,cn)) {
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }

        }

    }

    public static class SQLExtentions {

        public static bool Exists(this SqlDataReader rs, bool closeAfterReading = true) {

            bool hasRows = rs.HasRows;

            if (closeAfterReading) {
                rs.Close();
            }

            return hasRows;

        }

    }

}
```

But later, when I attempt to actually USE the extension:

```
var exists = new SQL_Data().DBReader("SELECT * FROM ...").Exists();
```

I get:

> .SqlDataReader does not contain a definition for 'Exists'

Even though `SQL_Data()` class, and it's `.DBReader()` method are both found and working, the extension method is not.

Any ideas?  Again, this is my first attempt at a .NET Core, so I do not know if there are peculiarities in config files, or properties dialogs that I've missed.

Both the `SQL_Data()` class, and the `SQLExtentions` class are in the same module: `SQLClass.cs`, in the same namespace, `CoreAPI1`.

Comment: Check that all places has correct `using`'s specified.

Comment: Extension methods have not changed since .NET Framework. They're exactly the same. So to debug, just do do what you'd do for .NET Framework.

Comment: These extension methods don't look clean or particularly user friendly. If you're looking for a cleaner way to work with SQL in .NET, have you looked into Dapper?

Comment: @GuruStron.  That did it.  I had the `using` statement, just not the right one.  If you will add that as an answer, I will give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments -
check that all places has correct `using`'s specified, such behavior can be sign of namespace missing/mismatched.

Comment: That turned out to be the issue.  I had omitted ONE particular "using" from my project.

Answer (score -1):

With the .Net Core the namespace System.Data.SqlClient will not be available as it was in .NET Framework you have to manual add it using NuGet.

Moreover, "cn" could not be found :)

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,cn)) {
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
```

Comment: @mason Read carefully, it mentions that the lib has to be downloaded separately and has nothing to do with extensions.